# expected singleton error odoo11 when using write function

Tags: odoo

Class A has a `One2many` field `Wproductlist` which points to Class B. i want to update the quantity field of stock.quant class by  subtracting quantity_needed field of classB. how can i achieve this? I tried the below code, but it shows singleton error when the class B has multiple records.

Class A:

```py
wproductlist = fields.One2many(comodel_name="class a", 
    inverse_name="ppp", string="Product List")

@api.multi
def update:
    d = self.env['stock.quant'].search([('product_id', '=', 
        self.wproductlist.productname)])
    for record in d:
            record.write({'quantity':quantity})
```

Class B:

```py
_name = "classa"

productname = fields.Char(string="Product Name")
ppp = fields. Char(string = "dummy")
quantity = fields.Char(string="Product Available")
```

Comment: You should atleast edit the code that it is syntactically correct python code...

Comment: Please correct me .. What the syntax error here

Comment: I have to make a list for all syntax errors in your example, and i won't do that ;-)

Comment: brother.. actaually the code is more than 4 pages.. so to make it short, i edited out some portions. Thats really happened..

Comment: Bro .. just check the `stacktrace` erro  post it, and post the method code that cause that error ^^

Comment: Haha.. thanks bro.. ithu ready aayittund enthayalum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see the where the error is even with the syntax errors as well as the errors in the field definition:

so the error is when you call `models.Model.search()` method you write in your domain `[('product_id', '=', self.wproductlist.productname)]` and in the definition of the model you defined `wproductlist` to be One2many field, meaning that `self.wproductlist` might (and in most of the cases) refer to more than one record by definition.

so when you try to get the `productname` from `self.wproductlist` which is referring to multiple records?

if you want to get all the values of `productname` in all records in `self.wproductlist` you should use the `.mapped()` method:

`product_names = self.wproductlist.mapped('productname')`

in this case the `product_names` is a list of all values of `productname` field in  all records referred to by `self.wproductlist`

in this call you have to change the operator to be `in` instead of `=`

`d =  self.env['stock.quant'].search([('product_id', 'in', 
    self.wproductlist.mapped('productname'))])`

this should solves your issue.

regards.

Comment: Thanks Brother.. It's worked already.. As a Beginner in Odoo, this comment is useful for me.. i never used mapped method in any of my classes..